# Need margin for LinearAxis by OxyPlot

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, styles, oxyplot

I use C#, wpf, OxyPolt.

[image]

I need margin for label "Title name, m".

```
xmlns:oxy="http://oxyplot.org/wpf"

<oxy:Plot>
   <oxy:Plot.Series>
      <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataVM}" 
                      StrokeThickness="2" DataFieldX="X" DataFieldY="Y"/>
   </oxy:Plot.Series>
   <oxy:Plot.Axes>
       <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Title="Title name"/>
       <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Title="Title name, m"/>
   </oxy:Plot.Axes>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use following property:   AxisTitleDistance="30"

```
 <oxy:Plot>
        <oxy:Plot.Series>
            <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataVM}" 
                  StrokeThickness="2" DataFieldX="X" DataFieldY="Y"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:Plot.Axes>
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" AxisTitleDistance="30" Title="Title name"/>
            <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" AxisTitleDistance="30"  Title="Title name, m"/>
        </oxy:Plot.Axes>
    </oxy:Plot>
```